# Why doesn't this regexp-replace work?

Tags: regex, racket, typed-racket

according to [this](http://www.regexr.com/), the regular expression `\W+([.:,.!?;])(.)` with the substitution group `$1 $2` does exactly what I want--reduces runs of whitespace and punctuation to the final punctuation mark, a space, then picks up where it was. For my purposes, this is perfect.

however, when I try this `(regexp-replace* #rx"\\W+([.:,.!?;])(.)" str "\\1 \\2")`
I just get `str` unmodified.

```
> (define str "ihmb e.  ?. ! hrg; ; ")
> (regexp-replace* #rx"\\W+([.:,.!?;])(.)" str "\\1 \\2")
- : String
"ihmb e.  ?. ! hrg; ;"
```

but I am expecting `ihmb e!  hrg;  "`

this is in Typed Racket, and I just updated to Racket 6.0

Comment: I'm wondering if it doesn't like the `\\W+` sitting there for some reason; try doing `"(\\W)+([.:,.!?;])(.)" str "\\2 \\3"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Racket supports basic and extended regular expressions.

To use the extended "Perl-ish" grammar that includes `\W`, you need to use `pregexp` or `#px` (not `regexp` or `#rx`):

```
(define str "ihmb e.  ?. ! hrg; ; ")
(regexp-replace* #px"\\W+([.:,.!?;])(.)" str "\\1 \\2")
```

In [the reference](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/regexp.html) read down until you get to this paragraph:

> The following completes the grammar for pregexp, which uses { and } bounded repetition and uses \ for meta-characters both inside and outside of ranges.

The stuff above that paragraph is the basic `regexp` and `#rx` grammar. The stuff below is `pregexp` and `#px`.

Although I don't know the whole history, I imagine the basic level is there for backward compatibility and to ease porting certain regexps.

Personally I just always use `pregexp` / `#px`, so that I know I can use the full grammar.

Comment: Thanks, Greg! Nailed it. And here I thought I could get away with just _skimming_ the full grammar...

Comment: That doc page has a _lot_ of information. I use `#px` so that I can simply use anything on that page that looks useful. :)